# Is there a way to replace java spring config (that has annotations) with xml config?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

So recently I've got the need to replace java configuration with xml. Most of the beans did not cause any problems, except for this one:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("kafka")
public KafkaHealthIndicator kafkaHealthIndicator() {
    return new MyIndicator();
}
```

Is there a way to implement the "ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator" annotation in the xml config file?

And in general, if I ever have the same task, is it possible to implement annotations used in java config in xml files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of converting Java to Xml, is it possible for you to import Java configurations in your xml?

Comment: well, it's kinda of a training task, to change various aspects of existing service, to be more familiar with how everything works and stuff

but what you say I guess makes sense, I can replace beans like that using import and others describe via pure xml